# How do I reattach a snapshot file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, snapshot

We've been trying to use snapshots on one of our test DBs in our automated testing so that we return to the prior state after the tests are complete. The restoring of the snapshot appears to have failed and the DB is stuck in restoring state so I'm trying to re-attempt the restore. However if I do a select on sys.databases the snapshot isn't listed even though I can still see it on the file system, is there anyway to re-attach the snapshot so I can restore it?

Comment: How many snapshots are there currently of this database?

Comment: @J.D Just one snapshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I didn't find a way around this issue, we ended up deleting the test DBs and pulling new backups from production.

Answer (score 0):

Snapshots have some limitations and what you request is one of them. Among the listed [Limitations on Database Snapshots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-snapshots-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#LimitsOnDbSS) you can see a limitation regarding reattaching a file:

> - You cannot attach or detach database snapshots.